# Simple regex: turn $text$ to \(text\) in Sublime Text

Tags: regex, latex, sublimetext2

In my work I have a very repetitive task, and I would believe that regex is a fast solution for it, though, my knowledge of regex is very sparse.

What I want to do is to in a txt-file find all occurences of

```
$text$
```

and replace them with

```
\\( text \\)
```

where text is LaTeX-code, so it can contain alphanumeric as well as other characters.

I plan to do this in Sublime Text, as it has a built in and convenient regex engine. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex:

```
\$([^$]*)\$
```

REplace With:

```
\\\\( \1 \\\\)
```